# How to load css and bootstrap files on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, localhost

I'm kinda new to HTML/JS and I am trying to make a web app for a uni project.  I used express to set up my server and load an HTML page. The HTML file loads other files (images, css) to display itself properly. Of course since these files aren't located on the localhost server but on my computer in my project  folder it can't find them to display them.

```
http://localhost:8080/bootstrap.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Do I need to upload them somehow? If yes how would I go about doing that in JS?

EDIT MORE INFO:
This is how my project looks: 
https://gyazo.com/ef316cf306e53f4b7caec39c4e103e66

and inside the vue(views in french)i have this: 
https://gyazo.com/f3ba3ece416a8ea7dda705c3b1366a3a

I run app.js via node to launch the app and loading my html using this code:

```
app = new express();
var path    = require("path");


app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/vue/accueil.html'));
});
```

In the accueil file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      [class*="col"] { margin-bottom: 20px; }
      img { width: 100%; }
    </style>
  <title>ACCUEIL</title>
</head>
<body> etc...
```

and

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/concert.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/u2.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/arianagrande.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/adele.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/imaginedragons.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/thecure.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/coldplay.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/onerepublic.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/calvin.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/alicia.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/wham.jpg" alt="Tigre"></div>
    </div>
```

Do i need to make an app.get for every image and css file maybe?

Comment: Upload them? Why not just reference them like you would any other remote file. Or better yet, put them somewhere in your root folder...

Comment: You should somehow serve them to the browser. You can use the express way of doing so. The documentation is here: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 1):

If your files are not located in the localhost folder, then, you "can't" load them in the code. (You can, but shouldn't)

You need to include everything inside your localhost folder, for example if you have your html in a folder called "myfirstwebsite" you need to have all the files inside that folder.

For example:

```
 myfirstwebsite
 |-index.html
 |-CSS
 |--bootstrap.css
 |-IMG
 |--welcome.jpg
 |-JS
 |--script.js
```

And then inside your HTML you load all the files that you need to display, for example your script with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

And the "script.js" will be loaded. Is the same with bootstrap, if you have bootstrap inside the css folder in your "myfirstwebsite" folder, then, you can call it with:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

And you should be able to load them now.

NEVER load your files outside of your server folder, like "file://c:/documents/bootstrap.css" because if you need to move/upload your site to another place outside of your PC, then, you will have a lot of problems.

Comment: Its seems to be what i have done, not working though. Editing the main question with more info about what i am doing (yesterday when i asked this it was late). Thanks for all the help though! <3

Comment: The code in the question shows that if you request `/js/script.js` from the server, it won't do anything. It isn't set up to serve those files. Moving the files won't help, you have to teach the JavaScript to respond to the request for them in the first place.